# What is the real advantage of writing Validations for Enum Types?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, enums, bean-validation

I don't understand the real benefit of implementing a custom validator for enum classes instead of directly handling the raised error, i.e., `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableExceptin`

Following what is reported in the various examples, for each Enum class I have to write two classes for validation greatly increasing the code, without my seeing any real benefit in error handling (e.g., automatic generation in the error message given by `String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";`). So why not directly write a single method in RestControllAdvice that handles the error for me?

Following the example given by [Validations for Enum Types](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums)
, I wrote for testing a custom validator for an enum class in spring boot

```
public enum GenderTypeEnum {

    MALE("male"),
    FEMALE("female");


    private final String value;


    private GenderTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

and

```
import com.example.springbootenumvalidator.enums.GenderTypeEnum;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenderTypeEnumValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidGenderTypeEnum, GenderTypeEnum> {
    private GenderTypeEnum[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidGenderTypeEnum constraint) {

        this.subset = constraint.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(GenderTypeEnum value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }
}
```

and

```
import com.example.springbootenumvalidator.enums.GenderTypeEnum;
import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

import java.lang.annotation.*;


@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(
        validatedBy = GenderTypeEnumValidator.class
)
public @interface ValidGenderTypeEnum {

    GenderTypeEnum[] anyOf();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

and

```
import com.example.springbootenumvalidator.enums.GenderTypeEnum;
import com.example.springbootenumvalidator.validator.ValidGenderTypeEnum;
import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserDTO {

    @ValidGenderTypeEnum(anyOf = {GenderTypeEnum.MALE, GenderTypeEnum.FEMALE})
    private GenderTypeEnum gender;

}
```

and

```
import com.example.springbootenumvalidator.dto.UserDTO;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class UserController {


    @GetMapping(path = "/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(

            @Valid
            @RequestBody
            UserDTO user

    ) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(user);

    }
}
```

With setting in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums=true
```

then

[image]

and

[image]

error message in console:

```
2023-06-11T09:17:23.702+02:00  WARN 16912 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.springbootenumvalidator.enums.GenderTypeEnum` from String "MALEXX": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [FEMALE, MALE]]
```

Comment: To be honest I never met such a validation in any enterprise project I worked on. The only reason of having such a validation I can think of is to limit the possible acceptable values - e.g. to charge the card - it has to be ACTIVE, but to restrict it, it can be NEW, ACTIVE or TEMPORARY_BLOCKED. But you can always use different enum types for every endpoint

Comment: Truly, I do not understand why baeldung and other authoritative voices propose writing a validator for enums as a good practice. It would suffice to write, with much less code, a method that intercepts the error and possibly a custom exception (NotValidEnumTypeArgoment Exception that extend RuntimeException) that can be raised when the input is not in the Enum class.

Comment: baeldung is far away from being an “authoritative voice”. A lot of the articles on that site are mediocre or even crap. It’s clearly a “quantity over quality” article collection.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense if you want to restrict user can only input a subset value of an enum.

You can of course create another separate enum that only containing these subset value , but then you need to implement some codes to map between this enum to the original enum. Although it is not difficult to do that , some people may not want to do it.